# To host a static (HTML) website on Google App Engine, what should be in the app.yaml file?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app.yaml

Can I use this for uploading HTML pages?

`app.yaml` contents:

```
application: visualvidya
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))
```

Comment: There's great documentation available on the App Engine website. The easiest way to host a static site would be with a `static_dir` block. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_directory_handlers

Comment: Also look at my new github project, it makes it easily host static sites on appengine while having ability to build it in jinja2. https://github.com/faisalraja/app-engine-static

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A minimal `handlers` section for a static site might look something like this:

```
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/index.html

- url: /
  static_dir: static
```

Every site is different, so as Sean pointed out in the comments, you'll want to consult [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig).