# How can I deploy an HTML5 web application in Google Cloud platform?

Tags: html, google-app-engine, cloud-platform

I am working on an HTML5 web application, which I need to host in Google cloud platform.

How can I deploy the web application, which is based on HTML5/CSS3, jQuery to Google Cloud platform/App Engine?

Clarification:
My web application is build using HTML5/CSS3 with javascript to process data. I am using Visual Studio IDE for development of the same. As per my understanding, apart from the supported languages like java, Python, etc, we can deploy html5 web application to Google cloud platform. How can I package my HTML5 application, which is not using any specific language and deploy to App Engine?

Thanks
Ambily

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy to a bucket directly:

> The Website Configuration feature enables you to configure a Google
>   Cloud Storage bucket to simulate the behavior of a static website. You
>   can define main pages or directory indices (for example, index.html)
>   for buckets and "directories". Also, you can define a custom error
>   page in case a requested resource does not exist.

No programming language at all required :)

[Google Cloud Storage](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration)

Comment: I am developing the HTML5 web application using Visual Studio; not Python. Is it possible to publish the web application developed using Visual Studio to App Engine or we need to use Python IDE for HTML5 web app development?

Comment: Visual Studio is an IDE, not a language. You have not mentioned the language you are using, so it is impossible to help you with specifics. Suggest you start here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction and you can currently use Java, Python, Go and PHP on app engine. So if you are not using one of those languages, you are out of luck. Start here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/

Comment: also check my edit to the answer for what might be your best non-code based option.

Comment: Thanks for all responses. My web application is build using HTML5/CSS3 with javascript to process data. I am using Visual Studio IDE for development of the same. As per my understanding, apart from the supported languages like java, Python, etc, we can deploy html5 web application to Google cloud platform. How can I package my HTML5 application, which is not using any specific language and deploy to App Engine?

Comment: This answer is suggesting you do *not* use Google App Engine.  Instead it suggests you use Google Cloud Storage, which is a different (and much simpler) service.  Basically you create a "bucket" and you can put files and folders into it in the same way as you can put files and folders into a folder on your computer. You need to figure out how to export all your HTML, CSS, JS, images, etc. out of Visual Studio into a folder where you can copy it into your Cloud Storage bucket -- then you can configure the bucket to be visible as a web site.

Comment: Your understanding is in fact incorrect. You do not deploy websites to appengine, you deploy programs. These programs might well generate a website when run. If you really want to deploy to app engine you'll have to learn how to use app engine with a static site. There are plenty of answers that relate to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296560/to-host-a-static-html-website-on-google-app-engine-what-should-be-in-the-app

Answer (score 0):

You need a account with Google Cloud Platform to start with. Assuming you have that.
Go to cloud console where you find all the admin menus for creating instances.

You need to create a compute engine instance, if you want to create full fledged website.

Steps to follow:

Create a instance (linux, 10GB  disk, 1.7GB memmory) and configure it for all required components.
After this you can move your files to your website folder usually "htdocs" 
You will be assigned with an empirical IP address.
Using zone management tools you can add a new domain. All that using the admin panel, no complexity involved.

You may required to configure proxy, if you need access to other machines.